# Parsing JavaScript in a Ruby Cucumber Code

Tags: javascript, ruby, testing, cucumber

I'm using Ruby Cucumber in my project and I need to check the result of a request (that's an HTML) and I would like to access an specific node through document.querySelector("myNode").

I'm getting an exception that tells me the expression "document"(from document.querySelector) does not exists. I'm thinking that the Cucumber does not recognizes my JavaScript code inside my Ruby code.

I would like to know how to evaluate an JavaScript code inside Ruby Cucumber code.

Does anyone knows if and how I can do it?

---

For example:

I have this javascript querySelector selected from a HTML file:

```
document.querySelector('.billOfSaleCellBoderBottom > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1)').lastChild.textContent.trim()
```

And it returns to me a string like this: '1199883322'

I need to use this string inside my ruby code to make some manipulations.

Could someone help with it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post an example of what you have tried so far.  You will get better answers more quickly if people can reproduce your problem and/or examine your code.  You might find this link useful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  :-)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it!